# TensorFlow: slice Tensor and keep original shape

Tags: tensorflow, slice

I have a Tensor `tensor` of shape `(?, 1082)` and I want to slice this Tensor into `n` subparts in a for-loop but I want to keep the original shape, including the unknown dimension `?`.

Example:

```
lst = []
for n in range(15):
    sub_tensor = tensor[n] # this will reduce the first dimension
    print(sub_tensor.get_shape())
```

Print output I'm looking for:

```
(?, 1082) 
(?, 1082)
```

etc.

How can this be achieved in TensorFlow?

Comment: Do you have any constraints as in the nature of splits,  n subparts needs to be equal? or n-1  equal parts and last part is leftover? 
```tf.split``` can be easily applied here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your problem can have many constraints, I can think of at least 3 solutions.
You can use `tf.split`. I'll use tf.placeholder, but it's applicable to tensors and variables as well.

```
p = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10], dtype=tf.int32)
s1, s2 = tf.split(value=p, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
```

However, this approach can become unfeasible if number of splits required is large. Note that it can split `None` axis as well.

```
for n in range(15):
    sub_tensor = tensor[n, :] 
s = tf.slice(p, [0,2], [-1, 2])
```

Slice can be used for multidimensional tensors, but it' pretty tricky to use. And you can use `tf.Tensor.getitem` method, almost as you described in your question. It acts  similar to `NumPy`. So this should do the job:

```
for n in range(10):
    print(p[n, :])
```

However, usage of these methods heavily depend on your particular application. Hope this helps.